# How can I update a question or answer without it popping to the top of activity

Tags: discussion

Why do questions or answers with new activity go to the top bicycle activity?  That is not how other SO sites behave.  I updated an old answer but I don't want to pop to the top.  If someone wants to sort by activity let them but why make it the default?

Comment: This is how all the other SO sites operate.  It is a little irritating at times, especially when a rep whore goes around doing trivial edits to tired old questions.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Or a badge whore.

Answer (score 9):

This behavior is the same across all Stack Exchange sites. Editing a post always bumps it to the front page. On busier sites there may be so much activity that the post does not remain on the front page for very long, but editing always bumps the post.

Comment: This functionality supports oversight of edits, it's a Good Thing.